# LARAVEL - Error relation (view)

Tags: laravel, view

I've one error whith a relation and I dont understand why;
Can you help me to solve this ? Thanks

```
Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo::$name (View: C:\wamp64\www\xxxxxx\resources\views\front\sujet\show.blade.php)
```

Code in the view:

```
<div>{{$poste->users()->name}}</div>
```

Code in the Model:

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Poste extends Model
{
    //
     public function sujets()
     {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Sujet');
     }

    public function users()
     {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\User');
     }
}
```

Controller:

```
$unSujet=Sujet::find($id);
        $lesPostes = Poste::orderBy('id')->where('sujet_id', $id)->paginate(15);
        return view('front/sujet/show', compact ('unSujet', 'lesPostes'));
```

And dd($poste->users()) return: (tested in the view directly in the foreach with $post)

```
BelongsTo {#268 ▼
  #foreignKey: "users_id"
  #otherKey: "id"
  #relation: "users"
  #query: Builder {#267 ▶}
  #parent: Poste {#261 ▼
    #connection: null
    #table: null
    #primaryKey: "id"
    #keyType: "int"
    #perPage: 15
    +incrementing: true
    +timestamps: true
    #attributes: array:7 [▼
      "id" => 1
      "description" => """
        Salut a TOUS Cest m on 1er sujet et mon 1er poste. \r\n
        \r\n
        mais ya un gros bug, c'est que ca écrit en majuscule tout seul ou alors c'est seulement pendant l'edition de ce message, mais c'est étrange et j'aimerais pouvoir écrire normalement :) !\r\n
        \r\n
        Merci,\r\n
        coardialement le bg.
        """
      "created_at" => "2017-03-31 11:14:48"
      "updated_at" => "2017-03-31 11:14:48"
      "signale" => 0
      "sujet_id" => 9
      "user_id" => 2
    ]
    #original: array:7 [▶]
    #relations: []
    #hidden: []
    #visible: []
    #appends: []
    #fillable: []
    #guarded: array:1 [▶]
    #dates: []
    #dateFormat: null
    #casts: []
    #touches: []
    #observables: []
    #with: []
    +exists: true
    +wasRecentlyCreated: false
  }
  #related: User {#266 ▼
    #connection: null
    #table: null
    #primaryKey: "id"
    #keyType: "int"
    #perPage: 15
    +incrementing: true
    +timestamps: true
    #attributes: []
    #original: []
    #relations: []
    #hidden: []
    #visible: []
    #appends: []
    #fillable: []
    #guarded: array:1 [▶]
    #dates: []
    #dateFormat: null
    #casts: []
    #touches: []
    #observables: []
    #with: []
    +exists: false
    +wasRecentlyCreated: false
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change relationship name to `user`. Laravel uses relationship name to generate foreign key by which it will search for related data.

Then you'll be able to get an object by adding `first()` method:

```
{{ $poste->user()->first()->name }}
```

Or you can do this:

```
{{ $poste->user->name }}
```

Comment: Both return "Trying to get property of non-object "

Comment: @emeliku you need to change relationship name to `user`

Comment: Change by what ?

Comment: @emeliku just change `public function users` to `public function user`

Comment: @emeliku you can't get the same error if you changed the name and using code from my answer.

Comment: @emeliku I've updated my answer with a better explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Can you show what the output is given by {{ $poste->users }}

From you output

```
#related: User {#266 ▼
#connection: null
#table: null
#primaryKey: "id"
#keyType: "int"
#perPage: 15
+incrementing: true
+timestamps: true
#attributes: []
```

It shows that there is no related user object found by the relation.

Print result of this

```
{{ $poste->user()->first() }}
```

If this gives empty array as output than you need it will confirm that either that poste is not belongs to valid user_id

Comment: Ok, so as we can see in the output there is no related user object is found by the  relation

Answer (score 0):

Your model look that is not related to user
at Model Posts:

```
public function user()
 {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\User', 'user_id');
 }
```

At model Users

```
public function postes()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Poste', 'user_id');
}
```

you can access the {{$poste->user->name}}

Good Luck